# Apple silicon m2 ERROR: Could not build wheels for lightgbm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip, lightgbm, apple-silicon

I am experiencing an issue with installing lighgbm on Apple Silicon, the full installation process is as follows:

```
python3 -m pip install lightgbm
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting lightgbm
  Using cached lightgbm-4.1.0.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from lightgbm) (1.10.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: lightgbm
  Building wheel for lightgbm (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for lightgbm (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      2023-11-02 14:58:09,352 - scikit_build_core - INFO - CMake version: 3.27.7
      *** scikit-build-core 0.6.0 using CMake 3.27.7 (wheel)
      2023-11-02 14:58:09,356 - scikit_build_core - INFO - Build directory: /private/var/folders/7t/ys9t4mvn1fx74wckbywxd2sw0000gp/T/tmptyogi8su/build
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2023-11-02 14:58:09,372 - scikit_build_core - INFO - Ninja version: 1.11.1
      2023-11-02 14:58:09,372 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - libdir/ldlibrary: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Python is not a real file!
      loading initial cache file /var/folders/7t/ys9t4mvn1fx74wckbywxd2sw0000gp/T/tmptyogi8su/build/CMakeInit.txt
      CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:35 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.
      
        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
      
      
      -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000040
      -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000040
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
      -- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)
      -- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
      -- Found OpenMP_C: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/include
      -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/include
      -- Found OpenMP: TRUE
      -- Performing Test MM_PREFETCH
      -- Performing Test MM_PREFETCH - Failed
      -- Performing Test MM_MALLOC
      -- Performing Test MM_MALLOC - Success
      -- Using _mm_malloc
      -- Configuring done (9.3s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: /var/folders/7t/ys9t4mvn1fx74wckbywxd2sw0000gp/T/tmptyogi8su/build
      *** Building project with Ninja...
      ninja: error: '/lib/libomp.dylib', needed by '/private/var/folders/7t/ys9t4mvn1fx74wckbywxd2sw0000gp/T/pip-install-zb1bf93d/lightgbm_d399d75f04b14379ba9d10c8bffd1542/lib_lightgbm.so', missing and no known rule to make it
      
      *** CMake build failed
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lightgbm
Failed to build lightgbm
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lightgbm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

as I understand I need to have libomp before installing lightgbm. However, I already have it installed and I still continue to experience the same issue. Is it related to the directories being different than where it is supposed to be? How can I check what the issue is?

```
brew install libomp      
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
#=#=-  #       #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               #=O#-     #        #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -#O=- #      #          #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -=O#-   #        #           #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -=O=-#      #        #            #                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -=O=-  #       #          #             #                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -=O=-     #        #           #              #                                                       ######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: libomp 17.0.4 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 17.0.4, run:
  brew reinstall libomp
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, basically I deleted the python that was installed and installed the python with homebrew then everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install \
   --no-binary lightgbm \
   --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_OPENMP=OFF \
   'lightgbm>=4.0.0'
```

I found the above solution in GitHub Reference Link: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/6035#issuecomment-1676415781

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

I also received the same error. For me running the below command worked

> conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm